# POST method not working in JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

Apologies for posting on a question which has already been asked multiple times on SO, but I have been through many of these and still cannot solve my own problem.

I have an index page, 'index.php' with a JQuery script which is intended to post an ID number to 'delete.php', in the same directory. 'delete.php' should then delete the row matching that ID number from a MySQL database. 'index.php' should also remove the deleted item from the HTML.

The last bit, removing the item from the HTML, works, but although I get a "200 OK" response in the error console, 'delete.php' does nothing - I have put in checking echo statements and do not run.

CODE 
index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                $(".deleteitem").click(function(){
                    var parent = $(this).closest('tr');
                    var id = parent.attr('id');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        URL: "delete.php",
                        data: "id=" +id,
                        success: function(data){
                            $('#'+id).remove();
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr id="1">
                <td>Milk</td>
                <td>3.99</td>
                <td><button class="deleteitem"><img src="deletebutton.gif"></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="2">
                <td>Bread</td>
                <td>1.99</td>
                <td><button class="deleteitem"><img src="deletebutton.gif"></button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

delete.php:

```
        <?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("tryit") or die(mysql_error());

$id = $_POST[id];

echo "DELETE.PHP HAS RUN<br>";

echo "ID = $id";

if (isset($id)) {
    $query = "DELETE FROM tryit WHERE id = '$id'";
    mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
}

?>
```

Any clue as to why this isn't working much appreciated - this is doing my nut in!

Comment: Why is `URL` in allcaps? It's probably posting to the same page.

Comment: are you sure mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") and 
mysql_select_db("tryit") are executing and your script is not dying there?

Comment: I tried changing the dbase connection to generate an error - no error message returned. I tried removing the connection completely, leaving just the echo statements - nothing returned. Even though I get a 200 OK response, delete.php is not being run. Also tried url in lower case - no change.

Comment: Try using something like firebug in firefox to check the HTTP requests made (so you can see if you're calling delete.php the right way)

Comment: Yes, I'm using Firebug's error console and get a 200 OK response, indicating that the connection to delete.php is OK. But still it doesn't run delete.php.

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP script, instead of `$_POST[id]`, you need to do `$_POST['id']`.

As for data, jQuery expects either an object or a query string. You're passing a query string so that should be fine.

Comment: `$_POST[id]` is a classical PHP bad-practice, :)

Comment: Yes, I see that, but it made no difference. delete.php is not running.

Comment: It was a typo -- but correcting makes no difference. 'delete.php' still does not run.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "delete.php",
    data: {id: id},
    success: function(data){
       $('#'+id).remove();
    }
});
```

**url** should be lowercase!

Comment: Hi - tried that; still no change. I am not getting anything echoed from delete.php, which now consists just of echos with the connection commented out:

 <?php
 //
 //mysql_connect("locaost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
 //mysql_select_db("tryit") or die(mysql_error());
 
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 
 echo "DELETE.PHP HAS RUN<br>";
 
 echo "ID = $id";
 //
 //if (isset($id)) {
 // $query = "DELETE FROM tryit WHERE id = '$id'";
 // mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
 //}
 
 ?>

Comment: I edited the answer, the problem was that URL should be 'url' (lowercase), jQuery didn't recognize URL and posted the request to itself (index.php)

Comment: I've changed url: to lowercase and removed everything from delete.php except the echo statements, so there can be no problem with the database connection. Still I get "200 OK" from the error console and no response from delete.php.

Comment: I ran your code with the changes I told you, It runs the delete.php script when a button is pushed and the script returns ' DELETE.PHP HAS RUN<br>ID = 2'. Status code 200 is a good thing, it means the script ran just right. Aditionally, you might want to return some code from the server so your javascript can know if the element was successfully removed so it can delete it from the DOM

Comment: It still doesn't work for me, with your reply copied and pasted in, I get no response from delete.php. I also tried it on a live server and still got nothing back from delete.php - the button and item disappear from the HTML but no echo messages are returned.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

The problem was not in the jquery (with the exception of the case sensitivity of 'url:', which was a typo).

The problem was just in the sql query. I had

```
$sql = "DELETE * FROM tryit WHERE id = '$id'";
```

whereas of course it should have been

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM tryit WHERE id = '$id'";
```

(with no *).